# Message Sending Order for Crossrider "appAPI.message.toAllTabs" method

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, message, crossrider

Message Sending Order for Crossrider `appAPI.message.toAllTabs` method

What is the crossrider message sending order and completion criteria for "appAPI.message.toAllTabs" method? For example, if I have 2 browser windows as below:

```
*Windows#1* [3 tabs: A1, A2 and A3]
*Windows#2* [2 tabs: B1 and B2]
```

**Q.1:** How does the method chooses which window to pick and then which tab to pick for sending messages?

**Q.2:** How do you know when the method has finished sending all the messages to all the tabs and the tabs have finished receiving the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is browser specific and where feasible implemented using their native APIs. Hence, it's not possible to describe a single order for sending messages.

Additionally, the current [appAPI.message.toAllTabs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message-method-toAllTabs) implementation does not provide a way to determine when the method has completed sending the messages, however, we are always interested in improving the experience for our users, and hence  I have forwarded your suggestion on to our product team, who will consider it for future releases. Thank you for your input.

If you have a specific use-case and want to discuss it further in private, please feel free to email our support (support@crossrider.com).

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Crossrider is great, but since it's hard to implement all the features that all the browsers offer or support, do you guys have any future plans to have some mechanism that will enable developers to use Crossrider and also enable them to use browsers' native APIs in conjunction with Crossrider as hybrid solutions. This way developers can use Crossrider 's cross-browser skeleton and also be able to implement browser specific APIs to satisfy their unique project needs.

Comment: We do our best to support all possible features so that they work for all browsers which sometimes means that some browser specific features are not possible to support for all browsers.

Having said that, with Chrome and Firefox it is often possible to use browser specific APIs from within the extension and differentiate between the browsers using appAPI.platform (http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-property-platform).